# VS2017: No Debugging XSLT in C# using XslCompiledTransform?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xslt

I have a CSharp app that uses XslCompiledTransform to convert a bunch of XML files to a particular ASPX layout. In the past in Visual Studio I was able to set breakpoints and step through the XSL code.  For example, see "XSLT from other languages" section on [this MS Doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xml-tools/how-to-start-debugging-xslt)

Now I am using Visual Studio 2017 and no breakpoints work, and I am unable to step through the code. Returning out of custom method calls in the CSharp code used to bring me back to the XSL code, but now does not.

I've tried everything I can find from Googling this. Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: I'm using Enterprise edition. Good point, I should have included that tag.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. Under Tools->Options->Debugging->General there's an option "Enable Just My Code".  That is ON by default and has to be turned off.

Hope this helps some other poor soul who is still dealing with XSLT! :-)[image]