# XslCompiledTransform XSLT debugginig

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xslt, xslcompiledtransform

According to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xml-tools/debugging-xslt?view=vs-2022) I should be able to debug my xslt transform by breakpointing then pressing F11 on the last line of code:

```
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new(true);
xslt.Load(stylesheetUri);
FileStream fileWriter = new(outputFile, FileMode.Append);
xslt.Transform(inputUri, null, fileWriter);
```

(`stylesheetUri`, `outputFile` and `inputUri` are all constant strings that represent filesystem paths for this example)

If I press F11 on the last line, it just does the transformation and moves to the next line (Same as Stepping over with F10). If I disable "just my code" as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50629409/vs2017-no-debugging-xslt-in-c-sharp-using-xslcompiledtransform), I just step into the framework's implementation of `Transform`.

Its worth noting that I have the stylesheet open in VS, and I have breakpoints throughout which trip when I manually start XLST debugging. (XML -> Start XLST Debugging (Alt-F5))

How can I start debugging XLST from a live application as the MS article suggests?

I'm using VS Professional 2022, v17.8.7 if that helps.

Ultimately, what i'd like to solve is that the XSLT debugger produces a different output to compiled transform on the exact same inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debugger only works in .NET Framework.

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/45158

Comment: So it has only been a known issue for 8y. A fix should be any day now!